# Создать свой числовой тип с допустимыми значениями

Tags: c++, delphi

На делфи я могу написать:

```
type
  TExample = -1..High(Word)-1;
```

Можно ли сделать что-то подобное в C++?
Если можно, то как?

```
// псевдокод
typedef int[-1..65534] TExample;
```

Comment: можно через класс такое реализовать, но тут вопрос зачем? Это будет работать дольше, а плюсов никаких

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch у меня High(Word) в функции - это минус один, переменная - 2 байта.
Чтобы случайно не передать ей лишнего и не словить переполнение

Comment: не нужно заново изобретать велосипед: познакомтесь с `throw try catch`

Comment: @Alex.B да бота для игрушки потихоньку переписываю с дельфийских сорцев на плюсы. Там во входящих пакетах лут в виде grp=1 байт и GID=2 байта
Но у меня, если GID=-1 в конфиге - настройка применяется ко всей grp

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, нет, спасибо, мне нужно велосипед, с механизмом исключений я прекрасно знаком

Comment: В общем суть в чем. Вопрос больше теоретический, нежели практический. Задачу-то я и доп проверкой могу решить, но мне интересно, как через typedef объявить тип и ограничить диапазон числа

Comment: А как ваш тип должен вести себя при переполнении? А какой у него должен быть размер в байтах? и т.д. и т.п. - вот потому это и не имеет смысла. Если в С++ что-то позарез нужно - так всегда самому написать можно свой `class` :) - в котором будет *точно* известно, что он делает.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если таки вам нужен велосипед, то ловите - думаю вы сами допишете нужный вам функционал:

```
#include<iostream>

class MyShort {
    public:
        static const int MAX_EL {65534};
        static const int MIN_EL {-1};
    private:
        int number_;
    public:
        MyShort () {
        };
        MyShort (int num) {
            if (num <= MAX_EL && num >= MIN_EL) {
                number_ = num;
            }
            else {
                number_ = -1;
            }
        };
        ~MyShort() {
        };
        MyShort &operator=(MyShort &a) {
            number_ = a.number_;
            return *this;
        };
        MyShort &operator=(int num) {
            if (num <= MAX_EL && num >= MIN_EL) {
                number_ = num;
            }
            else {
                number_ =-1;
            }
            return *this;
        };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyShort alfa {};
    alfa = 5;
    alfa = -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Но опять таки повторюсь: это лишено всякого смысла!!! Так как в памяти нет никакого разделения, это вопрос простой интерпретации: так -1 и 65535 - в памяти это абсолютно одинаковые последовательности бит (для 2-байтного типа). Так например:

```
 unsigned short alfa = -1;
 unsigned short beta = 65535;
 if (alfa == beta) {
     std::cout << "Comp" << std::endl;
 }
```

Будет выводит на экран сообщения (при этом если вы смените только на одном из чисел тип, то при сравнении они будут приведены к `int` и числа уже не будут одинаковы, так как это уже будут не 2-х байтные числа).

Comment: Спасибо конечно за труд, но почему такой ужас?( Неужели нельзя одной строчкой через typedef, как в дельфийском примере?(

Comment: @Robert это С++ - сделать так сделать не просто нельзя - это лишено всякого смысло (поэтому и нельзя). Ведь посудите сами: никих -1 или 65535 в памяти нет. Это просто последовательности бит, причем одинаковые!!! Это лишь вопрос восприятия и только

Comment: окей, тогда ещё вопрос: как создать числовой тип, чтобы ограничить в нем максимальное значение? чтобы, допустим, максимальным числом было 500?

Comment: enum class знаете ? enum class VeryShort: signed char{ A = -1, B = 0, C = 1, D = 2, ..., AAAAA = 500};

Comment: @Robert если нужен велосипед - то просто в коде выше заменяете константу `MAX_EL`, но это тоже не имеет смысла. И, кстати, по  поводу `enum` - это не вариант, не будете же вы определять 500 значений.

Comment: GRP видимо надо отдельным классом запилить.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch почему не будете ?
на [раз два](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9089441)

Comment: vegorov, да вы с ума сошли))
@AndrejLevkovitch, чего так сложно-то?( Должен быть более легкий путь или тогда какой вообще смысл от компилятора как от помощника

Comment: @Robert а в чём проблема ? Это самый просто способ. Сгенерировать часть заголовка и всё.

Comment: @vegorov, ага, ну давайте ещё макросы писать ради этого))
что-то мне с моего уютного дельфийского мирка переезжать перехотелось :D

Comment: @Robert вам просто следует понять, что базовые типы в Си и С++ не имеют строгой типизации и основаны только на битах и байтах.

Comment: @Robert я просто скопировал часть кода, который [реально существует](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9089442) и используется. Не хотите писать отдельный пользовательский тип (класс)- пишите enum. Не хотите писать enum - пишите класс.  Ни то ни другое - не пишите на C++.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, понятно, большое спасибо за разъяснение. в общем, по всей видимости, без сторонней библиотеки (или велосипеда) тут не обойтись =(
http://doublewise.net/c++/bounded/

Comment: enum можно легко начать с 500 :) чтоб не описывать все возможное, посмотрите stdbool.h - как там тип bool определён :) остальное от лукавого..

Comment: @Robert ну естественно, библиотеки же ещё есть. Забыл.

Comment: @Robert, в ссылке на библиотеку не обошлось без перла `Многие люди выбирают C ++ для производительности. ` :) но сама идея неплохая, только громоздкая..

Comment: Попробуйте так: `__extension__ typedef enum { ES = -1, EE = 500 } mytype_t;` как информация к размышлению..

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать ещё так:

```
__extension__ typedef enum __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
    ES = 500,
    EE
} mytype_t;

printf( "size: %zu\n", sizeof(mytype_t));
```

При такой схеме компилятор использует наименьший тип, который будет содержать все значения. Размер должен быть 2, по логике, и будет инкременироваться на 1 при каждом увеличении += 256.

Есть ещё опция `-fshort-enums` у GCC,clang это приводит тип `enum` к состоянию типа `signed short`..

Это конечно не готовое решение, но направление к размышлению, как это можно организовать с помощью расширений компилятора.

Answer (score 1):

Встречный вопрос автору: а чего вы хотите добиться?

Если генерации рантайм-проверок на выход из диапазона, то вы ошиблись языком. С++ наоборот избавляется в рантайме от всего, от чего можно избавиться. Нужна проверка - создайте собственный класс и перегружайте оператор присваивания.

Если хотите запихнуть этот диапазон в два байта и использовать -1 как сигнальное состояние, то вполне можете использовать как сигнальное состояние значение 65535, засунув его в константу. Если при этом оно должно быть меньше 0, то опять же класс и перегрузка операторов.

Delphi имеет другую специфику применения. Это, во-первых, наследник учебного языка Pascal, от которого требовалась строгость, а не скорость. Во-вторых, это язык для десктопных бизнес-приложений, где, теоретически, надежность важнее скорости.

Comment: Хочу выявлять ошибки на этапе компиляции, а не в дальнейшем. Чтобы, когда я в функцию передам значение, не входящее в диапазон - компилятор ругнулся и не дал собрать :)

Comment: вы считаете что у делфи медленный компилятор, и не достаточно оптимизированный код? это весьма спорное утверждение

Comment: @teran, про скорость компилятора я не говорил. А код на delphi, зачастую, медленнее чем на C++, потому что содержит множество дополнительных проверок и преобразований. И я не говорю что это плохо. Для большинства бизнес-задач надежность важнее скорости. Хотя и на С++ можно написать код, проигрывающий php